# In android, how should I put 2 buttons in one row having same width and height?

Tags: android

In android, how should I put 2 buttons in one row having same width and height? Which layout should I use?

Answer (score 11):

layout_weight is responsible for setting up components in equal or different proportions.

Use This :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button01" 
android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<Button android:text="@+id/Button02" android:id="@+id/Button02" 
android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If your question is solved then please mark this post as solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout for put more than one button in more than one row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```